# How to Get User Id_token of logged in user from azure ad without redirect using Client Id and Secret

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token

How to Get User Id_token of logged in user from azure ad without redirect using Client Id and Secret. we are trying oauth library authorize endpoint, but it redirects to call back url. We need just the Id_token of already logged in user.

Comment: Did your app log them in? Do you have a refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

1. You must ensure that your application is logged in and has received a refresh token.
   [image]
2. Use your refresh token to get id_token directly without having to redirect the url again.
   [image]